# How can I check for duplicate values without making an array?

Tags: java

I have a program that deals 20 cards based on the value of random numbers. So far it works to deal cards such as King of Spades, 2 of Hearts, etc. My job is to check whether or not the cards are duplicate using a method, but without an array. Here is my solution to checking duplicates which doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
    public class Driver {
        public static void main(String [] args) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
                Cards card1 = new Cards();
                Cards card2 = card1;
                if (card1 == card2) {
                    card1 = new Cards(); 
                }
                System.out.println(card1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my support class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Cards {

    String hearts = "Hearts";
    String diamonds = "Diamonds";
    String clubs = "Clubs";
    String spades = "Spades";

    String suit; 
    int cardNumber; 
    String numberName; 
    String suitName;
    Random randomNum = new Random();

    public Cards () {

    }

    public String suit() {
        int theRandom = randomNum.nextInt(4);

        if (theRandom == 0 ) {           
            suitName = "hearts";
        }
        else if ( theRandom == 1) {
            suitName = "diamonds"; 
        }
        else if (theRandom == 2) {
            suitName = "clubs";
        }
        else {
            suitName = "spades";
        }
        return suitName;
    }
    public String number() {
        int theRandomNum = randomNum.nextInt(12 + 1); 

        if ( theRandomNum == 1 ) {

            numberName = "Ace";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 2) {
            numberName = "2";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 3) {
            numberName = "3";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 4) {
            numberName = "4";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 5) {
            numberName = "5";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 6) {
            numberName = "6";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 7) {
            numberName = "7";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 8) {
            numberName = "8";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 9) {
            numberName = "9";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 10) {
            numberName = "10";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 11) {
            numberName = "Jack";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 12) {
            numberName = "Queen";
        }
        else if ( theRandomNum == 13) {
            numberName = "King";
        } 
        return numberName;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if (number() == "null") {
            return ("3" + " of " + suit());
        }

        return (number() + " of " + suit());
    }
}
```

Comment: Very sure you need an array to do this. or 20 different card objects

Comment: Well the problem is that my java book gives this problem as practice before they teach you arrays. My teacher said we're not allowed to use arrays.

Comment: If an array is not allowed, use ArrayList - put all your card in it and iterate over with a card, you want to check

Comment: We haven't learned array lists so they're not allowed either unfortunately.

Comment: How are your cards stored in memory without using an array?

Comment: They're not. I just have a for loop that creates an object and gives it 20 different values and prints it out. That's the main issue, but this is the part that my teacher helped me with. She's the one who basically wrote the method.

Comment: When you have cards with **20 different values** no card will be duplicate. I am afraid your question makes no sense.

Comment: What you need to do (without some how dynamically looping through them) is store them in an array. I can't see how it's possible without doing this. Are you sure you can't use arrays (or some other data structure)?

Comment: Well it just uses a random number and based on that number it gives the card a value. For example, if the random number is 1, it's a king, etc. The problem is that sometimes it gets two random numbers that are the same.

Comment: Can you use other data structures like LinkedLists?  Maps normally have arrays inside, and so do Lists and Sets, but a LinkedList should be fine

Comment: I was thinking I could use a .contains method on the strings. Would this be possible?

Comment: You could use a long and add powers of two and test if you already had this specific card with an "and" check on this number. E.g. your card has the value 4 -> test for: myCardBitField & ((long)Math.pow(2,4)) == true -> if not you have a new card, else you have a duplicate. This works as long as your cards all have a defined value and should be sufficient for 20 different values.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Could you post an example of using this below?

Comment: @alex23434 Has your "Card" Class any methods defined?

Comment: @Aron_dc I just checked out that way, storing the bits in the long as to which cards are taken, turns out the most you can store in a long is ~2e19 (using positive and negative), and to store 20 different cards you'd need 52!/32! = 3e32

Comment: Could you post an example below? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean (I'm new to this.). Also, I edited my above code @Aron_dc to show my support class.

Comment: @phflack This can't be true ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html ) In a 64 bit integer (thus a long in Java) written in two complements you have 63 bits for storing positive numbers. In Java 8 you even can use long in a unsigned variant.

Comment: @Aron_dc I'm not saying to treat it as signed, I'm saying to treat it as binary unsigned, since that's what we're going to be using it for.  Why should we care about negatives in this case?

Comment: @phflack We shouldn't but that still would give us a range of 2e63-1 -> 62 bits to use.

Comment: Can I use a contains method to solve this? My values are strings.

Comment: Yes you could. You just have to make sure to use a delimiter that doesn't appear in the strings that represent your card names.

Comment: But how would I do this? I've been thinking about it but I can't think of a solution

Comment: Strings are technically arrays, but I'm sure you'd be fine with using them.  Make each card have a unique `toString()` method, I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: @Aron_dc I'm still not sure what you're getting at for 62 usable bits in a long, I'm quite sure it clearly says a long is 64 bits

Comment: @phflack The maximum value you can store in a long is (if used in its normal signed variant) 2^63-1 thus you cant save the value 2^63 into a long variable. Thus the biggest power of two you can save into a long is 2^62.

Comment: @Aron_dc You are taking my words out of context.  We are not storing numbers, merely bits.  Longs can store 2^64 different combinations of bits.  Longs can be treated as more than just numbers.

Comment: @phflack I just think we were talking around each other. As alex23434 is clearly a beginner I think the approach of using the long as number is sufficiently (and sufficiently easy) for his problem. ;-)

Comment: @Aron_dc Longs are not big enough.  You'd need a BigInteger or some other larger value, but at that point you may as well just use arrays.

Comment: @phflack I still don't see the problem in saving 20 (or 52) flags in an long capable of serving as a 62 entries big bitField. Could you somehow explain where my maths break? O_o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93604/discussion-between-phflack-and-aron-dc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using a large String to store the cards that have been chosen:

```
String cards = "";

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Cards card = new Cards();
    while(cards.contains(card.toString()))
        card = new Cards(); //keep generating a random card until it's a new card
    cards += card.toString(); //add the card to the string of cards
    System.out.println(card);
}
```

This code would go inside the main method of your Driver class

Answer (score 1):

First your code has a small mistake

`int theRandomNum = randomNum.nextInt(12 + 1)`

while, determining from your following code you actually mean

`int theRandomNum = randomNum.nextInt(12)+1`

To store what cards you already had, you can just introduce a String and fill it step by step, always testing if the card you want to accept is not already contained in this String.

```
//This goes above the loop where you create your cards
String cards = "";

//This goes into the loop
while(cards.contains(card1.toString()){
    card1 = new Cards();
}
cards += card1.toString() + "#"; //Using # as a delimiter
System.out.println(card1);


//At the end you could also print your set of cards
System.out.println(cards);
```

It's not a very nice approach because you're not permitted to use arrays or similar structures but should do its work.

Please also keep in mind that class names are supposed to be singular. So not `Cards` but `Card`.

Comment: You don't need to add #, there shouldn't be any conflicts with `1 of Clubs` triggering on `11 of Clubs`, because 1 is Ace and 11 is Jack

Comment: @phflack Just look at it as a part of defensive programming ;-) But technically you're correct.

Comment: Another issue, if you get duplicates you won't generate the full 20 cards.  See my answer for an easier way to do it than with an if statement

Comment: Another issue, it doesn't look like you initialize card1 each time, unless you're keeping card1 and card2 from the original code?

Comment: The parts are meant to be inserted into his original code. It's not helpful to copy his whole code here just for the sake of three lines.